# Reuse code on all my tables

Tags: jquery, optimization, html-table

In my document I have four tables - TAB1 to TAB4.  I have the following code and I'm looking forward to apply it for all the tables.

```
$("#TAB1-check").click(function () {
if ($(this).val() == "Un-check All") {
    $(".TAB1").prop('checked', false).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    $(this).val("Check All");}
else {
    $(".TAB1").prop('checked', true).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    $(this).val("Un-check All");}});
```

And this piece of code:

```
$('#TAB1 td').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == ' search_value ') {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color','#FFFF00');}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
 $(".TAB1 .TAB2 TAB3").prop('checked', 
 false).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
```